# best solution to get values of multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get all values of multidimensional array like this

```
$post = array(
   'k'=>'kk',
   'l'=>'ll',
   'n'=>array(
       't'=>'tt',
       'n'=>array(
           'j'=>'jj',
           'h'=>'hh'
       )
   )
);
```

My approach to do that is :

```
$ordered = array();
foreach($post as $key=>$value){
    if(!is_array($value)){
        $ordered[] = $value;
    }else{
        $r = array_walk_recursive($value, function($v,$k) use(&$ordered){
            $ordered[] =$v;
        });
    } 
}
```

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => kk
    [1] => ll
    [2] => tt
    [3] => jj
    [4] => hh
)
```

i don't know if it's the best solution for it , i am consider the performance and backward compatibility with older php

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output as well ?

Comment: What about something as simple as `$ordered = [];
array_walk_recursive(
    $post,
    function($value) use (&$ordered) {
        $ordered[] = $value;
    }
);
var_dump($ordered);` ?

Comment: [Demo](http://ideone.com/83hH18)

Comment: @Mark i this the short version you submitted is the best solution tell now

Answer (score 0):

```
$ordered = array();
function myfunction($value, $key){
   $ordered[] = $value;
}
array_walk_recursive($post ,"myfunction")
var_dump($ordered);
```

Try this one. It may be work for your condition.

**EDIT**

```
$ordered = array();
    function myfunction($value, $key){
       global $orderd;
       $ordered[] = $value;
    }
    array_walk_recursive($post ,"myfunction")
    var_dump($ordered);
```

This will work correctly

Comment: "This will work correctly" <- It won't work correctly while there is a variable typo.  You did not test your code.